# Returns date ranges that have similar bookings on each day in the range linq

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I've a scenario with following requirements. Kindly help with it.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns date ranges that have similar bookings on each day in the range.
/// Read the example carefully.
/// Example : [{Project:HR, Date: 01/02/2020 , Allocation: 10},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 01/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:HR, Date: 02/02/2020 , Allocation: 10},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 02/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:HR, Date: 03/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 03/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:HR, Date: 04/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 04/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:HR, Date: 05/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 05/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:ECom, Date: 05/02/2020 , Allocation: 15},
///            {Project:ECom, Date: 06/02/2020 , Allocation: 10},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 06/02/2020 , Allocation: 15}
///            {Project:ECom, Date: 07/02/2020 , Allocation: 10},
///            {Project:CRM, Date: 07/02/2020 , Allocation: 15}]    
/// Returns : 
///          [
///            { From:01/02/2020 , To:02/02/2020 , [{ Project:CRM , Allocation:15 },{ Project:HR , Allocation:10 }]  },
///            { From:03/02/2020 , To:04/02/2020 , [{ Project:CRM , Allocation:15 },{ Project:HR , Allocation:15 }]  },
///            { From:05/02/2020 , To:05/02/2020 , [{ Project:CRM , Allocation:15 },{ Project:HR , Allocation:15 },{ Project:ECom , Allocation:15 }]  },
///            { From:06/02/2020 , To:07/02/2020 , [{ Project:CRM , Allocation:15 },{ Project:ECom , Allocation:10 }]  }
///          ]
/// </summary>
```

Here is my function needed implementation which will take input data and return date range that have similar booking on each day in range.

```cs
public IEnumerable<BookingGrouping> Group(IEnumerable<Booking> dates)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Class Code:These are classes used.
BookingGrouping.cs

```cs
public class BookingGrouping 
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
    public List<BookingGroupingItem> Items { get; set; } 
}
```

BookingGroupingItem.cs

```cs
public class BookingGroupingItem 
{
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public decimal Allocation { get; set; }
}
```

Booking.cs

```cs
public class Booking 
{
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Allocation { get; set; } 
}
```

Kindly help me to find the solution using LINQ
So far I've tried:

```cs
public IEnumerable<BookingGrouping> Group(IEnumerable<Booking> dates) 
{
    var data = (from booking in dates
                    group booking by booking.Date into dateGroup
                    select new
                    {
                        dateGroup.Key,
                        Bookings = from b in dates
                                    where b.Date.Day == dateGroup.Key.Day &&
                                    b.Date.Month == dateGroup.Key.Month &&
                                    b.Date.Year == dateGroup.Key.Year
                                    select new { b.Date, b.Project, b.Allocation }
                    }).ToList();


    return data; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: @AustinC I edited what I tried.

Comment: Try following : var groupDates = bookings.GroupBy(x => (x.Date.Day >= 2) ? new DateTime(x.Date.Year, x.Date.Month, 2) : new DateTime(x.Date.AddDays(-1).Year, x.Date.AddDays(-1).Month, 2)).ToList();